# How to achieve that Eclipse clean and build (aka rebuild)?

Tags: java, eclipse, helios, rebuild

I deleted my `./bin` folder in an Eclipse Indigo (super similar to Helios), and now I am wondering how to rebuild my Java project. I just cannot find a button like we can see in  Netbeans.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

For Eclipse you can find the rebuild option under *Project > Clean* and then select the project you want to clean up... that's all.

[image: Eclipse Clean projects selected below]

This will build your project and create a new `bin` folder.

Comment: This is the "Project" menu item.  (as in, next to File, Edit, Source, etc, etc).  I was initially right clicking the project and looking for it.  #justTryingToMakeItClear #upVoteForAnswer

Answer (score 16):

In Eclipse there is an "Auto Build" option, which is checked by default. When it is checked, you don't need to build your project, this happens automatically. If this behaviour is unwanted, uncheck this option and click build project whenever you want.

To clean a project, select Clean Project. This will delete the bin folder, however if Auto build is checked, it will be immediatelly regenerated.

Comment: I actually know. See the accepted answer, that was perfectly what I wanted :D

Answer (score 0):

In case you are unable to find a file in Eclipse code after pulling code from git or creating a file in intelliJ seperately (my case) you ca do the following

Right click on 'src' folder and in the menu that appear click on the 'refresh' button