# Project cannot run (compile) through eclipse from sourceforge CVS

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm new to sourceforge cvs. I just downloaded a Java project's source code through cvs. But when I try to run the it, it gives me `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. And I noticed that there is no bin folder created after i hit the 'run' button.

I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: which is the missing class?

Comment: Did you rebuilt your project?

Comment: ..Do you have a question?

Comment: all classes are missing. There is no bin folder created. I have rebuilt my project using 'clean'. And there is still no bin folder.

Comment: Try to do as the answer said: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803350/2040040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many a times developer doesn't store .project and .classpath files in repository. So, first check if .project and .classpath are present in your project's root folder.

- If No:

  - Then create a Java Project out of your source and add classpath dependencies.
- If Yes:

  - Then update classpath (build path)

After it, you need to compile your project.

You can google for how to create a Java Project and add classpath in Eclipse, internet is flooded with such examples