# No output appears in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm writing a code that output an output when using porlandc++ but when using eclipse it doesn't, a "Nothing to build for Help" message appears in the console. my file's name is "Help".
Even I've tried to debug it putting a breaking point on the first printf function in the code but the debugger always jump to  the end of the code?

I'm new with eclipse so I'll be grateful if you help

```
/*
 * help.c
 *
 *  Created on: ٠٨‏/٠١‏/٢٠١٤
 *      Author: Salahuddin
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int get_int(void);
double get_double(void);


int main(void)
{
int a;
double b;

    printf("Enter an integer : ");
    a=get_int();
    printf("The integer you entered is : %i",a);

    printf("Enter a double : ");
    b=get_double();
    printf("The double you entered is : %lf",b);

return 0;
}



int get_int(void)
{
int result;
    printf(">");

while(scanf("%i",&result)!=1)
{

    while(getchar()!='\n')
        ;
    printf(">");
}
return result;
}

double get_double(void)
{
double result;

printf(">");
while(scanf("%lf",&result)!=1)
{
    while(getchar()!='\n')
        ;
    printf(">");
}
return result;
}
```

By the way, when I started debugging, many threads appeared not just one, and when trying to stop them, all of them stop except the last one, don't know why?

as I said I'm new with eclipse trying to learn how to use it in debugging instead of the porland c++

thanks a lot

Comment: Is there suppose to be a header file listed after _#include_  ?? (perhaps <stdio.h>)  With that added, your code runs ok.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/iOQkaN. As suggested by @ryyker; I included `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Also, there is nothing in your posted code that suggests that multiple threads should be propagated.  Are you referring to some other phenomena?, such as many windows?, or many comments?, many error messages?

Comment: Thins is strange, I wrote #include<stdio.h> in the post, then it appears without <stdio.h>, I've tried to fix it but didn't succeed

Comment: many "Help.exe[C/C++ Application]" lines appear in the upper left "debug" window

Comment: regarding _Nothing to build for Help_:  If your environment is displaying this, it would seem to indicate that your project has already been built, and no element of that project has been changed since.  If you want to force a re-build, your environment should have an option to do that.  ***[LOOK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803350/645128)*** for an additional comment on how to do that.