# Eclipse stops at caught exception for no apparent reason

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm debugging my java code but eclipse keeps stopping as if I have a breakpoint in the following code (the code is from java's [HttpURLConnection](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java#L89), line 550):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public long getHeaderFieldDate(String name, long Default) {
        String dateString = getHeaderField(name);
        try {
            if (dateString.indexOf("GMT") == -1) { // stops here
                dateString = dateString+" GMT";
            }
            return Date.parse(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return Default;
}
```

`DateString` is null.

Note I DID uncheck "stop at unchecked exceptions" in windows > preferences > java > debug but even so the problem persists.

Comment: Most likely `getHeaderField()` is returning NULL. What's the behavior of `getHeaderField()`?

Comment: yes that is the problem but it's a builtin class by java so I cannot change it. Another thing is that the exception is caught and I have no breakpoint. Why does the debugger stop there?

Comment: Give it a _clean and build_ and try again.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803322/how-to-achieve-that-eclipse-clean-and-build-aka-rebuild but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: show us the `getHeaderField()` method

Comment: It is a built-in java method with the link in the post. here's the link to java's source code: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java#L89

Comment: The code here should be running fine, since the thrown `NPE` is caught by the `catch` clause. Try cleaning, rebuilding or restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Make sure in the [_Breakpoints_ view](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-breakpoints_view.htm) all Java exception breakpoints are disabled.

Comment: @howlger might want to convert that to an answer because it did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in the [Breakpoints view](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-breakpoints_view.htm) all **Java exception breakpoints** are **disabled**.