# Java Spring Boot Console App Override error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When trying to create a console application using Spring Boot, the @Override annotation is highlighted in red. All the necessary libraries are connected, I do not understand what the problem may be.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: *"I do not understand what the problem may be"* Then **read the error message**, by hovering over the red text. It'll tell you what is wrong, and knowing that makes it a lot easier to fix.

Comment: Also try to do a clean build. Looks like Eclipse, so: [How to achieve that Eclipse clean and build (aka rebuild)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803350/5221149)

Comment: if you hover the cursor, it writes: "The method run(String...) of type SBCA must override a superclass method"

Comment: Unless you're compiling with Java 5, it shouldn't say that.

Comment: Is it possible that I have an earlier version of Java installed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It was necessary to update the JRE System Library. The error was because there was a J2SE 1.5 library. Alt+F5 keyboard shortcut to update the project. The library has been updated to Java SE 1.8.